# TensorFlow: model saved successful but restore failed, where am I wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning TensorFlow recently, obviously I am a newbie. But I have tried many ways in this question, I wrote this code to train my model and want to directly restore it instead train it again if the `model.ckpt` file already exists. But after train, my test accuracy is about 90%, but if I restore it directly the accuracy just about 10%, I think it because I am failed restore my model. I just have two variables named `weights` and `biases`, this is my main-part code:

```
def train(bottleneck_tensor, jpeg_data_tensor):
image_lists = create_image_lists(TEST_PERCENTAGE, VALIDATION_PERCENTAGE)
n_classes = len(image_lists.keys())

# input
bottleneck_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE],
                                  name='BottleneckInputPlaceholder')
ground_truth_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes], name='GroundTruthInput')

# this is the new_layer code
# with tf.name_scope('final_training_ops'):
#     weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE, n_classes], stddev=0.001))
#     biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_classes]))
#     logits = tf.matmul(bottleneck_input, weights) + biases
logits=transfer_new_layer.new_layer(bottleneck_input,n_classes)
final_tensor = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

# losses
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=ground_truth_input)
cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cross_entropy_mean)

# calculate the accurancy
with tf.name_scope('evaluation'):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(final_tensor, 1), tf.argmax(ground_truth_input, 1))
    evaluation_step = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

image_order_step = tf.arg_max(final_tensor, 1)

saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), write_version=tf.train.SaverDef.V1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    if os.path.exists('F:/_pythonWS/imageClassifier/ckpt/imagesClassFilter.ckpt'):
        saver.restore(sess,"F:/_pythonWS/imageClassifier/ckpt/imagesClassFilter.ckpt")
        reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader('F:/_pythonWS/imageClassifier/ckpt/imagesClassFilter.ckpt')
        all_variables = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
        for each in all_variables:
            print(each, all_variables[each])
            print(reader.get_tensor(each))
    else:
        print("retrain model")
        for i in range(STEPS):
            train_bottlenecks, train_ground_truth = get_random_cached_bottlenecks(
                sess, n_classes, image_lists, BATCH, 'training', jpeg_data_tensor, bottleneck_tensor)
            sess.run(train_step,
                     feed_dict={bottleneck_input: train_bottlenecks, ground_truth_input: train_ground_truth})
            # 在验证数据上测试正确率
            if i % 100 == 0 or i + 1 == STEPS:
                validation_bottlenecks, validation_ground_truth = get_random_cached_bottlenecks(
                    sess, n_classes, image_lists, BATCH, 'validation', jpeg_data_tensor, bottleneck_tensor)
                validation_accuracy = sess.run(evaluation_step, feed_dict={
                    bottleneck_input: validation_bottlenecks, ground_truth_input: validation_ground_truth})
                print('Step %d: Validation accuracy on random sampled %d examples = %.1f%%' % (
                i, BATCH, validation_accuracy * 100))
        saver.save(sess, 'F:/_pythonWS/imageClassifier/ckpt/imagesClassFilter.ckpt')
        print(tf.get_session_tensor("final_training_ops/Variable",dtype=float))
        print(tf.get_session_tensor("final_training_ops/Variable_1",dtype=float))
    print('Beginning Test')
    # test
    test_bottlenecks, test_ground_truth = get_tst_bottlenecks(sess, image_lists, n_classes,
                                                                             jpeg_data_tensor,
                                                                             bottleneck_tensor)
    # saver.restore(sess, 'F:/_pythonWS/imageClassifier/ckpt/imagesClassFilter.ckpt')
    test_accuracy = sess.run(evaluation_step, feed_dict={
        bottleneck_input: test_bottlenecks, ground_truth_input: test_ground_truth})
    print('Final test accuracy = %.1f%%' % (test_accuracy * 100))

    label_name_list = list(image_lists.keys())
    for label_index, label_name in enumerate(label_name_list):
        category = 'testing'
        for index, unused_base_name in enumerate(image_lists[label_name][category]):
            bottlenecks = []
            ground_truths = []
            print("real lable%s:" % label_name)
            # print(unused_base_name)
            bottleneck = get_or_create_bottleneck(sess, image_lists, label_name, index, category,
                                                                 jpeg_data_tensor, bottleneck_tensor)
            # saver.restore(sess, 'F:/_pythonWS/imageClassifier/ckpt/imagesClassFilter.ckpt')
            ground_truth = np.zeros(n_classes, dtype=np.float32)
            ground_truth[label_index] = 1.0
            bottlenecks.append(bottleneck)
            ground_truths.append(ground_truth)
            image_kind = sess.run(image_order_step, feed_dict={
                bottleneck_input: bottlenecks, ground_truth_input: ground_truths})
            image_kind_order = int(image_kind[0])
            print("pre_lable%s:" % label_name_list[image_kind_order])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know where I am wrong..., the truth is that I have restore the model successfully, but because I create the result list every time by rand, when I use `image_order_step = tf.arg_max(final_tensor, 1)` to calculate the kind of the test image, because when I run the code next time, the lables order change, but the weight and biaese still the same to the last time, for example,for the first time,the lable list is [A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6],and after calculate the `image_order_step = tf.arg_max(final_tensor, 1)` result is 3,so the result will be `A4`, next time the lable list change to [A5,A3,A1,A6,A2,A4], but the `image_order_step = tf.arg_max(final_tensor, 1)` result still 3, so the predict result will be A6, so the accuracy will change every time and totally by rand...
This question tell me, be careful for the every detail, or a little ERROR will make you confusing for a  long time. OVER!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to save and restore:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver() 
with tf.Session() as sess: 
sess.run(initVar) 

# restore saved model
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my-model.meta')
new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))


# save model weights, after training process
saver.save(sess, 'my-model')
```

define a `tf.train.Saver` outside the session. After finish training process save the weights by `saver.save(sess, 'my-model')`. And restore the weights like above.

Comment: Thanks for help，but I am sorry to tell  it doesn't work either.The result still like what I said in the question, I don't know if the test data changing everytime influence the test accuracy,( the test data this time may be the training data last time). I think it has a little  influence to the result, but it shouldn't make the accuracy change from 90% to 10% or lower. This is all my code, if you have  free time, can you hlep me check it ?[TensorFlow transfer-learning](https://github.com/VoidBug/TensorFlow)